# Get all monitors info using UWP to push a blackout screen on them

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, fullscreen, uwp-xaml

Trying to build an UWP app to help my wife to blackout all of my computer monitors when bedtime and remove the blackout int he morning. for example blackout starts at 9pm and ends at 6am every day. But I'm having trouble find the correct api that will let me push all a xaml page instance to each monitor. So, I want to create a xaml page all black and send a new instance of that xaml to each of my monitors. But I can't get the API to grab the monitors info as I did on windows form using the following statement

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
```

All the code samples and ideas are based on winform.

How to get all monitors info using UWP to push a blackout screen on them?

Comment: Why not just set your power options to turn off the displays after x time of inactivity?

Comment: @ChrisW.  I'm rethinking my approach  and I believe that would way better.  So, when time frame is up I can change power option as ON.